# Publishing a google sheet using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below script was working till about a week ago.  I have checked the developer dashboard, and I cannot tell what has changed.  I am wondering if anyone has an alternative method for publishing a google spreadsheet via app script, or how I can get the script working again.

```
function publishSheet(sheetId) {
  //DriveApp.getRootFolder(); Needed for Scope
  if (!sheetId) {sheetId = "1gshaH5buTPFmm8elky0zWXqPYSO6BahK_OT7uFLrrgw"};

  var payload = {
    "published":true,
    "requireSignin":false,
    "entireDocument":true
  }


  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/cc..org/spreadsheets/d/"+sheetId+"/publishingsettings?id=" + sheetId
//  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/"+sheetId+"/publishingsettings?id=" + sheetId
  var options = {
    method:"POST",
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    headers:{
      Authorization:"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    payload:payload,
    muteHttpExceptions:true
  }

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  //Logger.log(resp) //no real response just some random characters. 
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, it just stopped working all of a sudden, and I can't figure out what changed to fix it.

Comment: When I try your code on my own sheet, I get an "Google Drive - Access denied" web page as response (can see it if I dump resp.getContentText()). Do you get the same too, or just no response at all and no published doc? Did you have to enable any advanced service to male your code work previously?

Comment: Did you change the sheetId to match the one of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Basically the function runs without an issue, but no longer publishes the spreadsheet.   It use to work last month.  Something on Google's end has changed.     So basically my question to the group is how can I publish a sheet using app-script?